# How to format axis number format to thousands with a comma

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the format of the numbers in the x-axis to be like `10,000` instead of `10000`?
Ideally, I would just like to do something like this:

```
x = format((10000.21, 22000.32, 10120.54), "#,###")
```

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create figure instance
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig1.set_figheight(15)
fig1.set_figwidth(20)

ax = fig1.add_subplot(2,1,1)

x = 10000.21, 22000.32, 10120.54

y = 1, 4, 15
ax.plot(x, y)

ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(2,1,2)

x2 = 10434, 24444, 31234
y2 = 1, 4, 9
ax2.plot(x2, y2)

fig1.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib : Comma separated number format for axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271564/matplotlib-comma-separated-number-format-for-axis)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use `,` as [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> format(10000.21, ',')
'10,000.21'
```

Alternatively you can also use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> '{:,}'.format(10000.21)
'10,000.21'
```

---

With [`matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter):

```
...
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
ax2.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
fig1.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks falsetru, adapting your code lines on matplot.ticker.FuncFormatter did the trick.

Comment: @IcemanBerlin, You're welcome. BTW, I used `int` to remove decimals. If you want keep it, drop `int`.

Comment: it was perfect, i did want to exclude decimals, i probably shouldnt have had them in the example. I did wonder what dropped them off though, so thanks again.

Answer (score 89):

The best way I've found to do this is with `StrMethodFormatter`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USDT&aggregate=1'
df = pd.DataFrame({'BTC/USD': [d['close'] for d in requests.get(url).json()['Data']]})

ax = df.plot()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: [Docs Tick Formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html)

Comment: Need to import matplotlib.ticker as calling it directly fails for whatever reason.

Answer (score 35):

I always find myself on this same page everytime I try to do this. Sure, the other answers get the job done, but aren't easy to remember for next time! ex: import ticker and use lambda, custom def, etc.

Here's a simple solution if you have an axes named `ax`:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,}'.format(int(x)) for x in ax.get_yticks().tolist()])
```

Comment: Nice… one-liner, and still fairly readable. Also, easy to modify, e.g. adding a dollar-sign: `...'${:,}'...`

Comment: I like this a lot, works great.  I had to put it after my range setter,  `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(20))`

Comment: Spits out an esoteric warning that I can't be bothered to look up or heed (`UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator`), but otherwise flawless.

Answer (score 21):

Short answer without importing `matplotlib as mpl`

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
```

*Modified from @AlexG's answer*

Answer (score 10):

If you like it hacky and short you can also just update the labels

```py
def update_xlabels(ax):
    xlabels = [format(label, ',.0f') for label in ax.get_xticks()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

update_xlabels(ax)
update_xlabels(ax2)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `matplotlib.ticker.funcformatter`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr


def func(x, pos):  # formatter function takes tick label and tick position
    s = '%d' % x
    groups = []
    while s and s[-1].isdigit():
        groups.append(s[-3:])
        s = s[:-3]
    return s + ','.join(reversed(groups))

y_format = tkr.FuncFormatter(func)  # make formatter

x = np.linspace(0,10,501)
y = 1000000*np.sin(x)
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_format)  # set formatter to needed axis

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: adapted from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271564/matplotlib-comma-separated-number-format-for-axis) answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = [10000.21, 22000.32, 10120.54]
```

You could use a list comprehension to make a list of labels, and then pass them the `plt.xticks`.

```
xlabels = [f'{label:,}' for label in x]
plt.xticks(x, xlabels)
```

Comment: This worked for me, for another problem that is not solvable with StrMethodFormatter! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way in my opinion:

```
current_values = plt.gca().get_yticks()
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in current_values])
```

From:
https://queirozf.com/entries/matplotlib-examples-number-formatting-for-axes-labels

Comment: agreed, this one's best and easiest; no additional imports, simple list comprehension. with f-strings it can be written a little more simply as
`plt.gca().set_yticklabels([f'{x:,.0f}' for x in current_values])`

Answer (score 3):

If you want original values to appear in ticks, use

```
plt.xticks(ticks=plt.xticks()[0], labels=plt.xticks()[0])
```

This will prevent abbreviations like from 3000000 to 1.3 e5 etc. and will show 3000000 (the exact value) in ticks.

Answer (score 2):

For non-comma separators, improving the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25973637/11671779), below answer will use `SEP` as the separator.

```py
SEP = '.'

ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(
        lambda x, p: str.replace(format(int(x), ','), ',', SEP)
    )
)
```