# How to adjust Python linear regression y axis

Tags: matplotlib, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I have been having Problems with price column every time I try to plot graphs on it and all my graphs have this problem and I want to change it to its actual values instead of decimals

[Example of of linear graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXgKf.png)

[This is the dataframe containing the information of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wSHy.png)

`Train` is the name of dataframe.

Column contains the selected

```
columns = ['Id', 'year', 'distance_travelled(kms)', 'brand_rank', 'car_age']

for i in columns:
plt.scatter(train[i], y, label='Actual')
plt.xlabel(i)
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please [do not post images of data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: The issue is that some prices are orders of magnitude larger than others. So, matplotlib is switching to linear scale with the exponent 1e7 here. Please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511476/how-to-properly-use-funcformatterfunc) helps.