# Call function on yaxis of matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to format the y-axis of my histogram with the function:

```
def convertCountToKm2(x):
    return x * 25.0 * 1e-6
```

Because this converts the histogram y-axis from a cell count to an area in km2. The histogram is created by:

```
bins = numpy.array(list(range(0,7000,1000)))
plt.hist(Anonzero,bins)
```

Which results in this figure:

[image]

I have tried calling the function with the following code:

```
yFormat = tkr.FuncFormatter(convertCountToKm2)
plt.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yFormat)
```

which returns an error: module `'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'yaxis'`

[How do I format axis number format to thousands with a comma in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973581/how-do-i-format-axis-number-format-to-thousands-with-a-comma-in-matplotlib) seems too have some hints about formatting the axis, but that is not specific for this case. I am unable to use it to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error tells you that `plt` (which I suppose is `pyplot`) has no `yaxis`, which is correct. `yaxis` is an attribute of the axes. Use

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(...)
```

Solving this you might run into another problem, that is that functions for the `FuncFormatter` need to accept two arguments, `x, pos`. You may ignore `pos`, but it has to be in the signature

```
def convertCountToKm2(x, pos=None):
    return x * 25.0 * 1e-6

yFormat = FuncFormatter(convertCountToKm2)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(yFormat)
```