# Matplot Histogram - Thousand separator x axis

Tags: python, histogram

Trying to include the thousand separator to the X-axis ticks of the following histogram.

```
plt.hist(df.Sales_Forecast,bins=20)
plt.xticks(list(range(0,50000,2000)),fontsize=14)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting y-axis matplotlib with thousands separator and font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734218/formatting-y-axis-matplotlib-with-thousands-separator-and-font-size)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying... Well I get this error message: "module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ticker'"
Even if I  imported matplotlib....

Comment: you need something like `import matplotlib.ticker as ticker` and then when the time comes something like `ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))`