# How to write the values of the y-axis in full when they are large numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

When I am plotting  `plt.scatter([0,1,2,3,4,5],[10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006])`, I obtain this figure :

[image]

I think that as I plot small variations of large values, the values are not written directly on the Y-axis and are replaced by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 + 1e4.

Is there a way to force the direct writing of the y-axis values: 10001, 10002, 10003 ,...  ?

I haven't found anything on the doc [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers here: [How do I format axis number format to thousands with a comma in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973581/how-do-i-format-axis-number-format-to-thousands-with-a-comma-in-matplotlib), I would recommend somthing like:

```
from pylab import *
plt.scatter([0,1,2,3,4,5],[10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006]);
gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
show();
```

You improve this!

Comment: I changed : gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
in gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:.0f}')) to obtain the format I wanted  (without comma). Thanks