# Matplotlib y axis value not show my data?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

In my dataset, I have a salary column like this

```
array([[  45000],
   [  50000],
   [  60000],
   [  80000],
   [ 110000],
   [ 150000],
   [ 200000],
   [ 300000],
   [ 500000],
   [1000000]], dtype=int64)
```

When I try to plot this using scatter the output come as shown in figure.

```
plt.scatter(features,label)
```

[image]

What I expected is like this.

[image]

I'm a beginner. Please solve my confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64118174/6797662)

```
from pylab import *

plt.scatter([0,1,2,3,4,5],[10001,10002,10003,10004,10005,10006]);
gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
```