# How to change point to comma in matplotlib graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to change on the `yticklabel` decimal separator from a decimal point to a comma, but leave the format of the offset text (1e-14), after using code from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271564/matplotlib-comma-separated-number-format-for-axis) or [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973581/how-to-format-axis-number-format-to-thousands-with-a-comma-in-matplotlib).

[image: 1]

My questions:

1. How can I change the point to a comma and save 1e-14?
2. How can I change `e` to `E` in the offset text?

I am using Python 3.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To change the decimal separator from a point to a comma, you can change the [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) to somewhere where a comma is used. For example, here I set it to German:

```
#Locale settings
import locale
# Set to German locale to get comma decimal separater
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()

# Tell matplotlib to use the locale we set above
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

# make the figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Some example data
x=np.arange(100)
y=4e-18*x**2

# plot the data
ax.plot(x,y,'b-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Changing the exponent to `E` in the offset text does not seem to be a simple task. You might start by looking at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517156/adjust-exponent-text-after-setting-scientific-limits-on-matplotlib-axis).

Comment: I needed to provide a locale in different format: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, ('pl_PL', 'UTF-8'))`. I wonder if in your response, shouldn't be `('de_DE', 'UTF-8')` **or** `'de_DE.UTF-8'` (maybe it is OS dependent?).

Comment: @matandked same for me. 'de_DE.UTF-8' works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the [answer of tmdavison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35937196/10325051):

Currently there is a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25006) in `matplotlib` where the locale is adapted once you run some `matplotlib` code.
You can check this via the following snippet

```
import locale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8")
current = locale.localeconv()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
new = locale.localeconv()
assert new == current
# Assertion Error!
```

To fix this you simply need to call first some `matplotlib` function and then set the locale. Kinda stupid I know :D

```
import locale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 1e-07, 10)

_, axes = plt.subplots()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8")
axes.ticklabel_format(useLocale=True)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]