# change decimal point to comma in matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib, formatting, decimal, locale, marker

I'm using python 2.7.13 with matplotlib 2.0.0 on Debian. I want to change the decimal marker to a comma in my matplotlib plot on both axes and annotations. However the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929775/how-to-change-point-to-comma-in-matplotlib-graphics) does not work for me. The locale option changes successfully the decimal point but does not imply it in the plot. How can I fix it? I would like to use the locale option in combination with the rcParams setup. Thank you for your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 


import numpy as np
#Locale settings
import locale
# Set to German locale to get comma decimal separater
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
print locale.localeconv()


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.rcdefaults()

# Tell matplotlib to use the locale we set above
plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True

# make the figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Some example data
x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y=np.sin(x)

# plot the data
ax.plot(x,y,'b-')
ax.plot([0,10],[0.8,0.8],'k-')
ax.text(2.3,0.85,0.8)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Here is the produced output: [plot with point as decimal separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpaVb.png)

Comment: You can in any case manually specify all strings and that `name.replace('.', ',')`, but I can imagine that that is not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer lies in using Python's formatted print, see [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). I quote:

> Type: `'n'`
>
> Meaning: Number. This is the same as `'g'`, except that it uses the current locale setting to insert the appropriate number separator characters.

For example

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

'{0:n}'.format(1.1)
```

Gives `'1,1'`.

---

This can be applied to your example using [matplotlib.ticker](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.StrMethodFormatter). It allows you to specify the print format for the ticks along the axis. Your example then becomes:

```
import numpy             as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import locale

# apply German locale settings
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

# make the figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# some example data
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

# plot the data
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')
ax.plot([0,10],[0.8,0.8],'k-')

# plot annotation
ax.text(2.3,0.85,'{:#.2n}'.format(0.8))

# reformat y-axis entries
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:#.2n}'))

# save
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

Which results in

[image]

---

**Note that there is one thing that is a bit disappointing. Apparently the precision cannot be set with the `n` format. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449950/2646505).**

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But this method raises a ValueError at my system, saying: ValueError: `Alternate form (#) not allowed in float format specifier`

Comment: @Lukason That might a difference between Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 then... You could try simply removing `#`, but that is probably still not exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Removing `#` works fine for me. I didn't need to define the precision further.

Comment: For me, this only works if `setlocale` is called after calling `subplots`. I suggest these lines be swapped in the answer. I'm using Python 3.9.9