# How to fix the precision with the `n` format

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to print a decimal using a comma as decimal separator. When I do this

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')

'{0:#.2n}'.format(1.1)
```

I get `'1,1'`. The comma is there, but the precision is only one, whereas I set it to two. How come?

---

Note this format is constructed as follows:

- `#`: "The `'#'` option causes the "alternate form" to be used for the conversion. ... In addition, for `'g'` and `'G'` conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the result."
- `.2`: Precision.
- `n`: "Number. This is the same as `'g'`, except that it uses the current locale setting to insert the appropriate number separator characters."

where the quotes come from the manual: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

---

Using `{.2f}` as suggested in the comments does not do what I want either: `'1.10'`. The precision is correct, but the comma from the locale is ignored.

Comment: What is ``n``? For floats ``f`` is used. And it works with ``.2f``.

Comment: It does not work with 2f as it prints 1.1

Comment: Technically `1.1` is a float not a decimal.

Comment: @Psytho, @BlueTomato, @Martin: The `n` is to obey the locale. `f` ignores this, see edit.

Comment: print(format('{0:#.2f}'.format(1.1)).replace('.',','))

Comment: @BlueTomato That works indeed, thanks. But I hoped that Python's mini specification language could take care of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `n` is used to print a `float`, it acts like `g`, not `f`, but uses your locale for the separator characters. And the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) of precision says:

> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or **before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`**.

So `.2n` means to print 2 total digits before and after the decimal point.

I don't think there's a simple way to get `f`-style precision with `n`-style use of locale. You need to determine how many digits your number has before the decimal point, add 2 to that, and then use that as the precision in your format.

```
precision = len(str(int(number))) + 2
fmt = '{0:#.' + str(precision) + 'n'
print(fmt.format(number))
```

Comment: Ok. That clarifies (I should be a better reader apparently). But how can I fix the precision? Or is that simply impossible?

Comment: I've added an example showing how to make the format dynamic.