# Custom scale with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to implement a custom scale (derived from `matplotlib.scale.ScaleBase`) and custom transform (derived from `matplotlib.transforms.Transform`) for special plotting of time-series, so it is solely used for the x-axis and for some form of datetime data, ie a numpy datetime array or a pandas `DateIndex`.

The transform needs to to know the actual times represented by the x values, but unfortunately floats are passed into the `Transform.transform_non_affine` method and there it has no idea what the time units are (seconds? minutes? hours? days?).

```
from matplotlib import scale as mscale
from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

class MyScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    name = 'myscale'

    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        super(MyScale, self).__init__()

    def get_transform(self):
        return MyTransform()

    def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
        return


class MyTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
    input_dims = 1
    output_dims = 1
    is_separable = True
    has_inverse = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTransform, self).__init__()

    def transform_non_affine(self, a):
        # ideally some time-dependent transforms here instead...
        print a, a.dtype
        return np.asanyarray(a)

    def inverted(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('not implemented')
```

Then if I do this:

```
t = pd.date_range('20160420 07:42', '20160421 12:12', freq='30T')
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(t.size), index=t)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.gca().set_xscale('myscale')
ts.plot()
```

I see the following print outs:

```
[ 24352302.  24354012.] float64
[ 24352302.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24354012.] float64
[ 24352380.] float64
[ 24352560.] float64
[ 24352740.] float64
[ 24352920.] float64
[ 24353100.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24353460.] float64
[ 24353640.] float64
[ 24353820.] float64
[ 24354000.] float64
[ 24352302.  24352302.] float64
[ 24352302.  24352302.] float64
[ 24352302.] float64
[ 24352302.] float64
[ 24352302.] float64
[ 24352302.] float64
[ 24353280.  24353280.] float64
[ 24353280.  24353280.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24353280.] float64
[ 24354012.  24354012.] float64
[ 24354012.  24354012.] float64
... 
[ 13.  13.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.] float64
[ 0.  1.] float64
[ 0.  1.] float64
...
[ 24352302.  24352332.  24352362.  24352392.  24352422.  24352452.
  24352482.  24352512.  24352542.  24352572.  24352602.  24352632.
  24352662.  24352692.  24352722.  24352752.  24352782.  24352812.
  24352842.  24352872.  24352902.  24352932.  24352962.  24352992.
  24353022.  24353052.  24353082.  24353112.  24353142.  24353172.
  24353202.  24353232.  24353262.  24353292.  24353322.  24353352.
  24353382.  24353412.  24353442.  24353472.  24353502.  24353532.
  24353562.  24353592.  24353622.  24353652.  24353682.  24353712.
  24353742.  24353772.  24353802.  24353832.  24353862.  24353892.
  24353922.  24353952.  24353982.  24354012.] float64
...
```

That long array is the actual array of datetimes, looks like it was converted to float with units of minutes:

```
.>>> np.datetime64(24352302, 'm')
numpy.datetime64('2016-04-20T02:42-0500')
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a reproducible example.

Comment: @IanS edited with a small example...

Comment: You could format the axis using the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8272640/5276797). Just change the function `func` to call `np.datetime64`.